# Dynamically load classes from other APK's

Tags: android, dynamic, frameworks, load, apk

I am creating a framework to be used by many departments in my work environment.  I need a way to dynamically load classes into the framework from individual department apk's.  For instance a way to dynamically load department A's content provider class into the framework.

I have had little luck trying to figure this out, any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect it would be a security hole if this was allowed and your design is risky as you are tightly coupling your program to someone else's.

A better solution is to be able to just use the content provider from your activity, much as you can access the contacts in Android.

Comment: It will be tightly coupled.  Essentially I have a service to send and receive data.  Applications can register with the service so when data is received it know where to store the content (hence the reason I need to be able to load the content provider class for that specific database).

I guess framework is not a good word.  Its more a development kit that provides a jar file to access the services.  But I'm stuck on this problem...

Comment: So put all the content providers in one place, but the advantage of Android is to just call out for a content provider that can handle what you need and save/update the data.  Android is based on loose coupling, so you may want to keep to that design.

Comment: I agree. This application will handle very sensitive information.  Right now I have a remote foreground service running that and receive and send network data.  APK's can bind to the service and register a broadcast receiver and a content observer.  The idea is that when new data comes into the phone it can be put into a db and trigger a content observer cursor that will send a broadcast.  This way the developer of the department apk's can handle call how they want.  It also guarentees that dead apk's will receive a signal that they have new data.  I just need a way to store the content

Comment: in the correct db.  I see doing this by using the apk's content provider.  This allows flexibly for department developers.  (Trust me one place sounds good - but this will potentially be used by hundreds of different departments - I needs to be dynamic and abstract but handle data flow)

Comment: James... I'm an idiot. Content providers are available to everyone.  I just need the correct URI for the received data.... which I have already.  Wow me.... Thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to load an already known class from another .apk currently installed on your device you can take the following approach (assuming your class has a default constructor). Also please remember that you must know the package name of the other .apk file and the other .apk file's package name must be different from your applications package name.

```
private Object loadClass(String packageName, String className){
    Object plugin = null;
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        DexFile df = new DexFile(appInfo.sourceDir);
        ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
        Class classToInvestigate = df.loadClass(className, cl);
        plugin = classToInvestigate.newInstance();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
    }
    finally{
        return plugin;
    }
}
```